# Mdx String generator

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, mdx

For Sql Server Analysis Services.

What im looking for is if anyone has example code of a class or function or a precompiled dll that you can pass columns, rows, pages, with filters etc. This then generates the mdx string.

im working in asp.net but should be able to convert from an example in any other language

Answer (score 2):

you can use excel to query the database, and use sql-profiler to see the mdx used in the query sent to Analysis Services.

You can set filters in Excel to see how these are placed in the MDX query.

Comment: how i can use excel for query from ssas?

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this myself yet, but I did recently become aware of this project which may be of use to you. http://code.google.com/p/ranet-uilibrary-olap/

Comment: i can not open this link!

Comment: yep, looks like they've pulled the code down. they went closed source for a while, now I think the project is dead

Answer (score 0):

> i can not open this link! – Ardalan Shahgholi Jul 31 '13 at 7:19
>
> yep, looks like they've pulled the code down. they went closed source for a while, now I think the project is dead – Darren Gosbell Mar 22 '15 at 21:58

Ranet OLAP project is alive, build of new version available for download on 
[Codeplex.com](https://ranetuilibraryolap.codeplex.com/). There are versions for WPF and HTML5 [(look online demo HTML5)](https://bi.galaktikasoft.com/js/RanetOlap/).
The source code is available for download on the website [Galaktikasoft](https://galaktikasoft.com/ranet-olap/download). It is not the latest version, but we plan to open it.